# How to reset sysctl to its OS defaults?

Tags: debian, sysctl, reset

I couldn't find an answer in the man pages for sysctl. My sysctl.conf file is still at its default state. I'm testing several values and loaded new settings via `sysctl -p newsettings.conf`. I thought it would be sufficient for reseting to do `sysctl -p` (which means that it reads the values from `sysctl.conf`), but a fast `sysctl -a | grep domain` revealed that they are still the old settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know there is no "undo" for `sysctl` -- You need to re-enter the default settings (typically `/etc/sysctl.conf` simply does not specify defaults, so re-reading it won't revert your changes unless there's an explicit setting).

If you do not know your default settings a reboot will get them back, and you can then list them with `sysctl -a` (store this somewhere for reference).  If you have another mostly-identical machine around you can grab the `sysctl -a` output from that host instead of rebooting.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Rebooting would be a possibility and then `sysctl -a > sysctl_defaults.conf` should do the trick. I'll leave this open for some time, maybe somebody else knows a way. If not I'll accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Make sure you're storing the sysctl values somewhere where they aren't being routinely read at boot (like `~/sysctl_defaults.conf`) -- Though it doesn't happen often sometimes the default value for a given sysctl knob changes, and you could introduce some accidental strangeness that way.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that and I stored them in my home directory as you have proposed. I also made sure that nothing is in `/etc/sysctl.d` before rebooting. Everything worked like a charm and I think your solution is totally fine. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Sysctl Defaults**

On CentOS 7, look at

```
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/
```

to get the default settings that ship with the OS.